# Modifications to Content Editor for Accessibility Input Labels

Tags: content-editor, content-management, speak, accessibility

Is there a Sitecore supported or unsupported way of modifying html structure of Content Editor and Experience Editor for the purpose of supporting screen readers used for accessibility/visually impaired content authors?

For context this is a new project using Sitecore 9.3 and SXA. Horizon is not fully compatible with SXA yet so we need to support Content Editor and Experience Editor.

Simple example:

1. Open Content Editor
2. Edit a Page with content fields (title,
   description, body)
3. Use a screen reader like JAWS to show all form
   fields
4. It displays and reads a list of fields, but almost all of
   them show up as Unlabeled. So an author can't tell what they are
   editing.

[image: Sample screen shot]

Can we customize/hack with JavaScript the markup to make it more screen reader friendly?

Sitecore should be using labels:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Good example of what labeled forms look like:
https://webaim.org/articles/jaws/forms.htm

Thanks for the help!